# ionic app showing white screen on android mobile

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I made login and registration page on ionic framework. It working perfectly on browser but when i build android app by command `ionic build android` and install it on my mobile it showing white page but in my laptop browser it working perfectly my html code is

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-messages.js"></script> 
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
        <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<script id="auth.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Xenforo Login" class="sigin-background">  

    <ion-content class="padding">

    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Login</h2><br/>

    <form name="authorizationForm" novalidate="" ng-submit="signIn(authorizationForm)"> 

    <div class="list">

    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : authorizationForm.username.$invalid, 'no-errors' : authorizationForm.username.$valid}">
    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="authorization.username" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    </label>

    <div class="error-container" ng-show="authorizationForm.username.$error && authorizationForm.$submitted" ng-messages="authorizationForm.username.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="error-list.html"></div>
    </div>

    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : authorizationForm.password.$invalid && authorizationForm.$submitted, 'no-errors' : authorizationForm.password.$valid  && authorizationForm.$submitted}">
    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="authorization.password" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    </label>

    <div class="error-container last-error-container" ng-show="authorizationForm.password.$error && authorizationForm.$submitted" ng-messages="authorizationForm.password.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="error-list.html"></div> 
    </div>          

    </div>     

    <button class="button button-full button-positive" type="submit">
    Sign In
    </button>
    <a class="button button-full button-positive" href="#/register">Sign Up</a>
    </form>   

    </ion-content>

    </ion-view>
</script>  

   <script id="register.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Xenforo Registration" class="sigin-background">  

    <ion-content class="padding">

    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Registration</h2><br/>

    <form name="registrationForm" novalidate="" ng-submit="signUp(registrationForm)"> 

    <div class="list">

    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : registrationForm.username.$invalid, 'no-errors' : registrationForm.username.$valid}">
    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="authorization.username" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    </label>

    <div class="error-container" ng-show="registrationForm.username.$error && registrationForm.$submitted" ng-messages="registrationForm.username.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="error-list.html"></div>
    </div>

    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : registrationForm.email.$invalid && registrationForm.$submitted, 'no-errors' : registrationForm.email.$valid  && registrationForm.$submitted}">
    <span class="input-label">Email</span>
    <input type="password" name="email" ng-model="authorization.email" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    </label>

    <div class="error-container last-error-container" ng-show="registrationForm.email.$error && registrationForm.$submitted" ng-messages="registrationForm.email.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="error-list.html"></div> 
    </div>
    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : registrationForm.password.$invalid && registrationForm.$submitted, 'no-errors' : registrationForm.password.$valid  && registrationForm.$submitted}">
    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="authorization.password" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    </label>

    <div class="error-container last-error-container" ng-show="registrationForm.password.$error && registrationForm.$submitted" ng-messages="registrationForm.password.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="error-list.html"></div> 
    </div>          


    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : registrationForm.repeatepassword.$invalid && registrationForm.$submitted, 'no-errors' : registrationForm.repeatepassword.$valid  && registrationForm.$submitted}">
    <span class="input-label">Repeat Password</span>
    <input type="password" name="repeatepassword" ng-model="authorization.repeatepassword" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    </label>

    <div class="error-container last-error-container" ng-show="registrationForm.repeatepassword.$error && registrationForm.$submitted" ng-messages="registrationForm.repeatepassword.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="error-list.html"></div> 
    </div>


    </div>     

    <button class="button button-full button-positive" type="submit">
    Sign Up
    </button>

    </form>   

    </ion-content>

    </ion-view>
</script> 


<script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Second page">
    <ion-content class="padding">
    <h1>Wellcome</h1>
    </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</script>   

<script id="error-list.html" type="text/ng-template">  
    <div class="error" ng-message="required">
    <i class="ion-information-circled"></i> 
    This field is required!
    </div>
    <div class="error" ng-message="minlength">
    <i class="ion-information-circled"></i> 
    Minimum length of this field is 5 characters!
    </div>
    <div class="error" ng-message="maxlength">
    <i class="ion-information-circled"></i> 
    Maximum length of this field is 20 characters!
    </div>
</script>
```

My angular code is below

```
var nameApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngMessages']);

nameApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('auth', {
      url: '/auth',
      templateUrl: 'auth.html',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl'
    })
    .state('register', {
      url: '/register',
      templateUrl: 'register.html',
      controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    })
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/auth");

});


nameApp.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.authorization = {
    username: '',
    password : ''   
  };  

  $scope.signIn = function(form) {
    if(form.$valid) {
      $state.go('home');
    }
  };  

});



nameApp.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.authorization = {
    username: '',
    password : '',   
    repeatepassword : ''   
  };  

  $scope.signUp = function(form) {
    if(form.$valid) {
      $state.go('auth');
    }
  };  

});


nameApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

i don't know where i am wrong please help me

Comment: Are you getting output after white screen?

Comment: No, I am not getting any output .You can see the screenshot from my mobile on the following link:
`http://imgur.com/02c5bx1`
For the confirmation i have tested this on some other mobiles as well and get the same output. 
 I am including this angular-message.js using `CDN` and when i try to do that on the browser by download it and including it from the path I got the same white screen output on the web as well. So thats why I am sure that I am getting this error due to that. 
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-messages.js"></script>`

Comment: Which version of ionic framework you are using?

Comment: I am using CLI v1.7.14

Answer (score 1):

If it is running properly in browser and not in device, your can use google chrome browser and enter the url  **chrome://inspect** to check the console and find out the error occuring in device. There may be some plugin issues. This can be done only in android mobile running android OS ver
. kitkat or higher

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are declaring that your app is an Angular app. Try adding this attribute to your `body` tag:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
```

Comment: Have you tried the absolute path:  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect you app using Chrome Remote Debugging on Android. You are already using CLI 1.7.14 then you don't need to make any configuration to inspect app on WebView . Follow link will help you to setup your android device to inspect ionic app on chrome devtool-
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging 
This helped me a lot to debug my app on real environment.

Answer (score 0):

In line

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-messages.js"></script>
```

include `http:` or `https:`.